# Bash Script To Recursively Move

Tags: bash, shell

I have a directory structure like this:

```
|--Photos  
   |--2014-01-15 #2  
      |--IMG_0045.JPG  
      |--IMG_0051.JPG  
   |--2014-06-19  
      |--IMG_0078.JPG
```

Notice one folder's name contains a space [ 2014-01-15 #2 ].  I wrote a bash script to move only the *.JPG files in all the folders using this:

```
#!/bin/bash
for i in $(ls); do  
    if [ -d $i ]; then
        cd $i
        mv *.JPG /opt/data/tmp/
        cd -
    fi
done
```

I understand that the script didn't go into the folders with names that contained spaces because of word splitting.

Is there a bash script you could write in order to move *.JPG files from all folders?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Simply `mv */*.JPG /opt/data/tmp` will do what you ask.

Your script has two common beginner errors. You need to [put double quotes around all variables which contain file names,](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10067266/when-to-wrap-quotes-around-a-shell-variable) and you should [not be using `ls` to find files](http://mywiki.wooledge.org/ParsingLs).

Personally, I would also advise against using `cd` in most scripts.

If you need to loop over directories in other scripts, `for i in ./*/; do`... does that.

If you need to recurse arbitrarily deeply nested directories, `find` does that. With GNU `find` and GNU `mv`, `find dir -type f -name '*.JPG' -exec mv -t /opt/data/tmp {} +`

Comment: Oh, and you mistyped `i` after `for`

Comment: tripleee your solution did do exactly what I was looking for - thank you and also for the additional advice. Edited to correct mistype after for.